# Отмена операции после git log

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-log

Прошу ответить без надменности. Многим это покажется не проблемой и смешным. После git log  не могу дальше ничего печатать. Ctrl+С не работает. Нажимал кучу других кнопок ничего не помогает. Что нужно сделать, чтобы отменить блокировку набора текста?
VSC

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нажмите <kbd>Q</kbd>, от слова "quit".

Тот же самый хоткей выходит из `less`, возможно git сам вызывает less.

Comment: спасибо, помогло.